# Transform stops responding when radio buttons are moved to another div

Tags: html, css, web, sass

I have a bunch of radio buttons that control the rotation of 3D cube. Each radio button is responsible for displaying the cube from one of its sides. It works like a charm when the radio buttons are contained in body and not in the div. However, as soon as I move them to a div element, my cube won't rotate anymore.

So, here is the HTML for radio buttons:

```
<body>
<input type="radio" checked id="radio-front" name="select-face"/>    
<input type="radio" id="radio-back" name="select-face"/>
<input type="radio" id="radio-left" name="select-face"/>
<input type="radio" id="radio-right" name="select-face"/>
</body>
```

The CSS is as follows and it works great:

```
#radio-back:checked ~ .section1 .scene .cube {
  transform: rotateY(180deg); 
} 
#radio-left:checked ~ .section1 .scene .cube {
  transform: rotateY(90deg); 
} 
#radio-right:checked ~ .section1 .scene .cube {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg);   
}
```

Now, I put the radio buttons in a div so it looks like this (at this point it stops rotating):

```
<body>
<div id="radioButtons">    
<input type="radio" checked id="radio-front" name="select-face"/>  
<input type="radio" id="radio-back" name="select-face"/>
<input type="radio" id="radio-left" name="select-face"/>
<input type="radio" id="radio-right" name="select-face"/>
</div>
</body>
```

Accordingly, I change the CSS:

```
#radioButtons #radio-back:checked ~ .section1 .scene .cube {
  transform: rotateY(180deg); 
} 
#radioButtons #radio-left:checked ~ .section1 .scene .cube {
  transform: rotateY(90deg); 
} 
#radioButtons #radio-right:checked ~ .section1 .scene .cube {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg);   
}
```

I expected that it should work, but it doesn't. Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong? I am willing to learn, so in case my question is too bad, I'd appreciate if you pointed me to some source that I could use to understand my mistake.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are using the siblings selector, in order for it to work they have to be well siblings, so .section1 has to be in the same container as your radio-front etc

Comment: [Adjacent Siblings Selector MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) note the "adjacent" in the name